# Objective-C: typedef NS_ENUM error

Tags: objective-c, ios, enums, typedef

I'm using a typedef NS_ENUM in an iOS-App and I get this error: "linker command failed with exit code 1". Normally thats very easy to fix, but this time I can't find the solution...

This is my NS_Enum:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MKIGridViewSelectionStyle)
            MKIGridViewSelectionStyle_SelectCellOnly = 1,
            MKIGridViewSelectionStyle_SelectCompleteRow = 2,
            MKIGridViewSelectionStyle_SelectCompleteColumn = 3;
```

EDIT:

The complete Message:

> Ld /Users/mki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GridViewTest-esfqwoooiarqpchfzsazwbgckmso/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GridViewTest.app/GridViewTest normal armv7s
>       cd /Users/mki/Desktop/GridViewTest
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -L/Users/mki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GridViewTest-esfqwoooiarqpchfzsazwbgckmso/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/mki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GridViewTest-esfqwoooiarqpchfzsazwbgckmso/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/mki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GridViewTest-esfqwoooiarqpchfzsazwbgckmso/Build/Intermediates/GridViewTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/GridViewTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/GridViewTest.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -framework QuartzCore -framework AudioToolbox -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/mki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GridViewTest-esfqwoooiarqpchfzsazwbgckmso/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GridViewTest.app/GridViewTest
>
> duplicate symbol _MKIGridViewSelectionStyle_SelectCellOnly in:
>       /Users/mki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GridViewTest-esfqwoooiarqpchfzsazwbgckmso/Build/Intermediates/GridViewTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/GridViewTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/MKIViewController.o
>       /Users/mki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GridViewTest-esfqwoooiarqpchfzsazwbgckmso/Build/Intermediates/GridViewTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/GridViewTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/MKIGridView.o
>   ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7s clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Maik

Comment: You're going to need edit your question to paste in the linker output.  To find it, choose View > Navigators > Show Log Navigator.  Then click on the topmost “Build *YourTarget*” line in the log navigator.  Then look through the log and find the linker output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot to use curly brackets around the value definitions.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MKIGridViewSelectionStyle) {
        MKIGridViewSelectionStyle_SelectCellOnly = 1,
        MKIGridViewSelectionStyle_SelectCompleteRow = 2,
        MKIGridViewSelectionStyle_SelectCompleteColumn = 3
};
```

Comment: Also make sure the "typedef" is there, without it you can also see a similar duplicate symbol error.